# Join two dataframe with two columns [ one of datetime column ] in R

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

I have two df and I'm trying to left or right join them based on two-column. ID and Datetime column. how do I allow DateTime from another df to match the first df even if it's within 10-20sec difference range?

df1 :

| ID | Datetime |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | 2021-04-02 09:50:11 |
| 456 | 2021-04-02 09:50:15 |

df2:

| ID | Datetime |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | 2021-04-02 09:50:31 |
| 456 | 2021-04-02 09:50:23 |

if the times are within 10-20 diff on df2, return all the columns and DateTime column from the df2 to new,df3.  For all matching IDs and yyyy-mm-dd H:M matches to both dfs. so if the change in :SS is between 10-20 on df2, pick it and do join, If its not within 10-20sec range,skip. someone, please help?

Comment: Your condition is not clear.  Is this based on all IDs or wherever this happens

Comment: @akrun For all matching IDs and yyyy-mm-dd H:M matches to both dfs. so if the change in :SS is between 10-20 on df2, pick it and do join.

Comment: My confusion is if at least one of the ID have a difference not between 10 and 20, then do you use 'df1' as the df3

Comment: @akrun If its not within 10-20sec range , skip that and it wont be used on join

Comment: Why not first join by ID, than add a variable that calculates the difference between the two times, and then filter out those cases whose differences are in your desired range?

Comment: Provide a sufficient big data with at least 10-15 row using `dput`. See [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269) . Show the expected output for the data shared. This will make it easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Your sample data is very minimalistic. Not sure how you wanetd to implement the 10-20 secs. I assumed everything within -20 to +20 seconds should be matched. This can easily be adjusted in filtering part `ID == i.ID & Datetime <= (i.Datetime + 20) & Datetime >= (i.Datetime - 20)`.

Here is a `data.table` approach

```
library(data.table)
# Sample data
DT1 <- fread("ID    Datetime
123     2021-04-02T09:50:11
456     2021-04-02T09:50:15")
DT2 <- fread("ID    Datetime
123     2021-04-02T09:50:31
456     2021-04-02T09:50:23")
# Set datetimes to posix
DT1[, Datetime := as.POSIXct(Datetime)]
DT2[, Datetime := as.POSIXct(Datetime)]

# possible rowwise approach
DT1[, rowid := .I]
setkey(DT1, rowid)
DT1[DT1, Datetime2 := DT2[ID == i.ID & Datetime <= (i.Datetime + 20) & Datetime >= (i.Datetime - 20),
                          lapply(.SD, paste0, collapse = ";"), .SDcols = c("Datetime")],
    by = .EACHI][, rowid := NULL][]

#     ID            Datetime           Datetime2
# 1: 123 2021-04-02 09:50:11 2021-04-02 09:50:31
# 2: 456 2021-04-02 09:50:15 2021-04-02 09:50:23
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, the OP wants to retrieve those rows of `df2` (including all columns) which have a matching `ID` in `df1` *and* where the time difference of the time stamps `Datetime` between `df1` and `df2` is less or equal than a given value.

So, for the given sample data

- if the allowed time difference is 20 seconds at most both rows of `df2` are returned.
- If the allowed time difference is 10 seconds at most only the second row of `df2` with `ID == 456` is returned.
- If the allowed time difference is 5 seconds at most an empty dataset is returned because non of `df2`'s rows fulfills the conditions.

One possible approach is to use a *non-equi join* which is available with [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table):

```
library(data.table)
timediff <- 10 # given time difference in seconds
setDT(df1)[, Datetime := as.POSIXct(Datetime)] 
setDT(df2)[, Datetime := as.POSIXct(Datetime)]
df2[, c("from", "to") := .(Datetime - timediff, Datetime + timediff)]
df3 <- df2[df1, on = c("ID", "from <= Datetime", "to >= Datetime"), 
           nomatch = NULL, .SD][
             , c("from", "to") := NULL][]
df3
```

> ```
>     ID            Datetime
> 1: 456 2021-04-02 09:50:23
> ```

If the code is run with

```
timediff <- 20
```

the result is

```
df3
```

> ```
>     ID            Datetime
> 1: 123 2021-04-02 09:50:31
> 2: 456 2021-04-02 09:50:23
> ```

If the code is run with

```
timediff <- 5
```

`df3` becomes an empty data.table.

#### EDIT: Show `Datetime` from `df1` *and* `df2`

By [request of the OP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68333546/join-two-dataframe-with-two-columns-one-of-datetime-column-in-r/68340326?noredirect=1#comment120842865_68340326), here is a version which returns both `Datetime` columns from `df1` *and* `df2`, renamed as `Datetime1` and `Datetime2`, resp.,:

```
library(data.table)
timediff <- 20 # given time difference in seconds
setDT(df1)[, Datetime := as.POSIXct(Datetime)] 
setDT(df2)[, Datetime := as.POSIXct(Datetime)]
df2[, c("from", "to") := .(Datetime - timediff, Datetime + timediff)]
df3 <- df2[setDT(df1), on = c("ID", "from <= Datetime", "to >= Datetime"), 
           nomatch = NULL, .(ID, Datetime1 = i.Datetime, Datetime2 = x.Datetime)]
df3
```

> ```
>     ID           Datetime1           Datetime2
> 1: 123 2021-04-02 09:50:11 2021-04-02 09:50:31
> 2: 456 2021-04-02 09:50:15 2021-04-02 09:50:23
> ```

Comment: How do i include both the datetime columns in df3? when timediff<-20 ? @Uwe